# Recursive Function - Is Prime

Tags: python, algorithm, math, logic, primes

What's the logic behind `if n < i*i: return True`?

```
def isPrime(n, i = 2):
 
    # Base cases
    if (n <= 2):
        return True if(n == 2) else False
    if (n % i == 0):
        return False
    if (n < i*i):
        return True
 
    # Check for the next divisor
    return isPrime(n, i + 1)
```

Comment: Let's say `n == 13` and `i = 4`. If `n` is not divisible by any dividers below `4` it's a prime number.

Comment: `return True if(n == 2) else False` can be replaced with `return n==2`

Comment: The logic is that you don't need to check divisors that are greater than the square root of the candidate number.

Answer (score 1):

For each factor `f`, there is a complement `n/f`. If the factor is less than `sqrt(n)`, the complement is bigger, and vice versa. So, if we checked all factors up to and including `sqrt(n)`, and found none, it is sufficient to say that there are no other factors.

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration, we establish that `n` is not divisible by an integer less than or equal to `i`. If `n` were not a prime, then by definition `n = x * y` where `x` and `y` are positive integers. Both `x` and `y` must be greater than `i` as mentioned earlier. It follows that `n = x * y` must be greater than `i * i` for it to possibly be a prime.